# How to find smallest integer which is greater than N positive primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, estimation, integer-programming

I know this can't be computed exactly, but I just need a rough estimate. I know one can compute a rough estimate of the number of primes less than N using the famous formula:

`PI(N) = N / Log(N)`

But what about the reverse case? What if someone gives me the value of PI(N) (say 25) and asks me for the value of N. Is there a known formula for it?

Example: Upto which integer you must examine to find the first 168 primes? The answer is 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been [known since the early 1960s](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~ramare/TME-EMT/Articles/Art01.html) that

$$n(\log n+\log\log n−3/2)<p_n<n(\log n+\log\log n-1/2)$$

for $n\gt19$, where $p_n$ denotes the $n$th prime.  Of course all this says, for the example the OP gave, is

$$884\le p_{168}\le1051$$

(after rounding the decimals up and down, respectively).  The fraction $3/2$ in the lower limit has been improved to $1$ for all $n$, so that we can say

$$968\le p_{168}\le1051$$

The fraction $1/2$ in the upper limit has also been improved (to $0.9484$), but only for large $n$ (i.e., $n\gt39017$).

Comment: Reading your answer I realized that definitive upper bound (`n(log n + log log n - 1/2)`) and not approximation is what I need. Thank you for the good answer.

Answer (score 4):

This can be approximated by $f(n)=n\log n$ where the logarithm is natural (base $e$). A better approximation is
$$
f_1(x)=x\log x+x\log\log x-x
$$
and a still better approximation is the inverse logarithmic integral.

Taking your example of 168, the three methods give 860, 967, and 934. (Here the second is best, but once the numbers get past 50,000 or so the third one is better, and quickly becomes far better.)

Comment: The [Mathworld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RossersTheorem.html) states that the equality is really a $\gt$ and the difference of the two sides grows as about as $0.46x$

Comment: @RossMillikan: I'm familiar with Rosser's theorem, but the difference between $p_n$ and $n\log n$ should be about $n\log\log n$, not $0.46n$. (Notationally, I'm defining $f$ and $f_1$ and then claiming that these approximate the $n$-th prime; I'm certainly not saying that these give the $n$-th prime exactly!)

Comment: Rosser's is a true lower bound, but is generally rather low.  We could usually get away with $-0.54x$ (at least up to $n=10^7$).  I thought OP would be interested, hence the comment.

Comment: Thank you. This is very informative.

Comment: @dotNET: You're welcome. Let me know if you need anything else -- bounds, error estimates, etc.